How to specific image ext when upload using window.showOpenFilePicker?
Here is the MDN documents.
MDN
On it's sample:
const pickerOpts = {
    types: [{
        description: "Images",
        accept: {
            "image/*": [".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"],
        },
    }, ],
    excludeAcceptAllOption: true,
    multiple: false,
};

But I found that the ext list not working.
I can pick every type of images.
What should I do to implement limit the file types just present the ext List using showOpenFilePicker?
Here is a quick Promis demo function which you can reporduce it.
Open developer console, just paste below.
const callFileWindow = ({
        types,
        multiple,
        excludeAcceptAllOption,
        mimeType,
        description,
    }) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (window.showOpenFilePicker) {
            const options = {
                types: types ?
                    [
                        mimeType ?
                        {
                            description: description || "Images",
                            accept: {
                                [mimeType]: types.map((type) => "." + type),
                            },
                        } :
                        {
                            description: description || "Images",
                            accept: {
                                "image/*": types.map((type) => "." + type),
                            },
                        },
                    ] :
                    undefined,
                excludeAcceptAllOption,
                multiple,
            };
            console.log('opt', options)
            window
                .showOpenFilePicker(options)
                .then((fileHandles) => {
                    Promise.all(
                        fileHandles.map((fileHandle) => fileHandle.getFile())
                    ).then((files) => {
                        resolve(multiple ? files : files[0]);
                    });
                })
                .catch(reject);
        } else {
            const input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "file");
            input.setAttribute("accept", types.map((t) => `.${t}`).join(","));
            if (multiple) {
                input.setAttribute("multiple", "");
            }
            input.onchange = () => {
                if (input.files.length === 0) {
                    reject(new Error("No file selected"));
                } else {
                    resolve(multiple ? input.files : input.files[0]);
                }
            };
            input.click();
        }
    });
callFileWindow({
    types: ['png', 'jpg'],
    multiple: true,
    excludeAcceptAllOption: true
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
callFileWindow({
    types: ['png', 'jpg'],
    multiple: true,
    excludeAcceptAllOption: true
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})

after that you will find every type of images can be selected.
I guess the image/* works, but ".png",  ".jpg" not.
